# Как сделать анимацию полёта дрона над городом

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

У меня есть анимированное SVG дрона, но вращаются только винты нет перемещения в пространстве.

```css
.drone .body  {
   fill: #111111;
  }
   .wing {
    fill:black;
   transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes wing {
   100% {
    transform: rotateY(7200deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="964" height="538" viewBox="0 0 964 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">

  <g transform="scale(2.5) translate(20,20)">
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
      <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/>    </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
      <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9
       c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5
       C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0
       c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5
       c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
      </g>   
      
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Есть изображение города, над которым бы я хотел изобразить полёт дрона

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось совместить в одном SVG и изображение дрона и картинку города

С помощью команды  анимации перемещения `translate(x,y)`

```
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate"
   begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="100,20;900,500;100,20" 
   repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
```

Мне удалось заставить перемещаться дрон над картинкой

*Анимация начнется после клика на картинке*

```css
.drone .body  {
   fill: #111111;
  }
   .wing {
    fill:black;
   transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }
  @keyframes wing {
   100% {
    transform: rotateY(7200deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="964" height="538" viewBox="0 0 964 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fgQA.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>   
  <g transform="scale(2.5) translate(20,20)">
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
      <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/>    </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
      <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9
       c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5
       C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0
       c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5
       c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
      </g>   
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="svg1.click" dur="10s" values="100,20;900,500;100,20" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
    </g>
  </svg>
```

Но выглядит это не реалистично.

Как сделать, чтобы траектория полёта дрона была не прямолинейна, также чтобы дрон менял свои размеры в зависимости от положения над картинкой.

Comment: Добавлен  [второй ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1112311/28748). Более сложная и на мой взгляд, более интересная анимация

Answer (score 14):

Для движения дрона по криволинейному пути необходимо получить криволинейный `path`

Для этого загружаем изображение в векторный редактор и рисуем кривую:

Начальную точку движения и конечную точку я расположил недалеко друг от друга, чтобы было незаметно перепрыгивания дрона при втором цикле движения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняем файл в формате SVG и копируем его `path` в файл анимации.

Чтобы заставить дрон двигаться вдоль этой кривой, используем команду анимации

```
 <!-- Анимация движения дрона -->
          <animateMotion id="move"  begin="btn1.click+3s;move.end+1s" dur="35s" repeatCount="10" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
            <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
          </animateMotion>
```

"#trace" - это, как раз полученный из векторного редактора криволинейный `path`

`begin="btn1.click+3s;move.end+1s"` логическая цепочка запусков анимации движения дрона:

- Первый запуск после клика по кнопке id="btn1"
- Второй запуск `move.end+1s` начнется после окончания этой же анимации с секундной
  задержкой

**Note**

В отличии от анимации CSS, нет необходимости мучительно высчитывать тайминги в абсолютно исчислении времени.
Реализация логики в SVG более близка к человеческому языку,- одна анимация закончится, с секундной задержкой начнется другая и, что более ценно, эту логику можно поменять в любой момент, не опасаясь, что все остальное, как в CSS нужно будет пересчитывать.

**Добавлена для оживления полёта анимация сигнальных фонарей или видео камер дрона**

```
    <!-- Сигнальные фонари, камеры -->
            <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="23" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
                   <animate id="op1" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op1.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
         </ellipse>
            <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="32" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
                   <animate id="op2" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op2.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
         </ellipse>
```

```css
.drone .body {
   fill: #050423;
  }

   .wing {
   fill: #000;
    transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
  }

  .drone.animate .wing {
   animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes wing {
   100% {
    transform: rotateY(7200deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<svg class="drone animate"  height="40vh" viewBox="-3 -3 60 20" >
    <defs>
   <<radialGradient id="Lg" fx="50%" fy="50%"  >
   <stop offset="5%" stop-color="yellow"  />
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red" />
  </radialGradient>    
    </defs> 
   <g >
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
      <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/>    </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
      <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9
       c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5
       C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0
       c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5
       c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
    
      </g>
         <!-- Сигнальные фонари, камеры -->
      <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="24" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
             <animate id="op1" attributeName="opacity" begin="0s;op1.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </ellipse>
            <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="32" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
             <animate id="op2" attributeName="opacity" begin="0s;op2.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </ellipse>   
    </g>  
   
  </svg>
```

Логика та же, что и в предыдущей анимации

После завершения анимации, пауза 2 секунды `begin="0s;op1.end+2s" dur="1s"` снова начинается та же самая анимация. Небольшой нюанс - первая анимация повторяется 3 раза (три моргания) `repeatCount="3"`

**Уменьшение, увеличение размера дрона**

```
   <!-- Анимация увеличения, уменьшения дрона -->
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" 
          begin="btn1.click" dur="10s" values="2.5;2;1;1.5;1.5;2.5"
          repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
```

Дополнительные пояснения даны в комментариях к коду

Используется трек Мирей Матье Парижский Вальс
Анимация начнется после клика на кнопку **Start**

### Update

Добавлены пешеходы

```css
.container {
width:98vw;
height:auto;
}
.drone .body  {
   fill: #111111;
  }
   .wing {
    fill:black;
   transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes wing {
   100% {
    transform: rotateY(7200deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<div class ="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 964 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
<defs>   

          <!-- Трасса полёта дрона -->
  <path id="trace" d="m67.5 74.7c0 0 250-57.3 280.8 31.7 27.3 78.8-364.7 78.1-175.7 168.6 57.2 27.4-133.6 75.2-132.7 136.3 0.4 27.7 33.7 62.3 60.8 56.7 29.1-6 19.6-56.8 35.8-81.7C172 332.1 356.5 275.2 293 245.6 165.4 186.2 429.9 139.4 429.2 66.3 428.5-0.7 476.5 31.8 495 45.5c53.2 39.5-46.1 148.9-2.5 198.9 22.2 25.6 47.4-74.7 83.4-69.9 43 5.8 47.8 115.7 74.2 106.9 58.1-19.5 7.8-198.2 76.7-192.5 64.3 5.4 72.9 133.2 40.8 189.2-17.1 30-74.9 7.2-98.3 32.5-18.9 20.4 3 65.2-20 80.8-37.8 25.7-96.9-42.2-135.8-18.3-32.1 19.7-5.1 87.4-37.5 106.7-77 45.7-276.3 45.5-265-43.3 9.5-74.9 161.9 62.4 154.8-45.1-10.1-151.8 334.5 159 445.2 100.1 39.7-21.1 76.8-74.9 65-118.3-7.7-28.4-66-17.3-75.8-45-9.9-27.9 37.3-54.4 30.8-83.3-7.3-32.8-70.2-37.3-71.7-70.8C758.1 149.2 644.6 150.1 626.3 103.4 605 48.9 580.9 163.7 525.7 127.2 398.4 42.9 69.2 91.3 69.2 91.3" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#ec0000"/>
             <!-- Красная трасса для пешеходов -->
<path id="redTrace" d="m291.7 535.6c0 0 52.2-34.2 79-50.1 24.7-14.7 50-28.4 75.4-41.8 28.4-14.9 57.3-28.8 86-43 22.7-11.3 45.4-22.8 68.4-33.6 19.3-9 38.8-17.5 58.3-25.9 14.8-6.4 29.8-12.3 44.5-18.9 13.8-6.2 27.1-13.3 41-19.4 7-3.1 13.7-7.2 21.2-8.8 6.1-1.3 18.9-0.6 18.9-0.6" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#e00"/>
             <!-- Зелёная трасса для пешеходов -->
 <path id="greenTrace" d="m826.7 535.1c0 0-3.8-25.5-5.9-38.3-2.1-12.8-4.1-25.6-6.5-38.3-2.3-12.6-5.4-25.1-7.7-37.7-1.6-9.2-2.5-18.5-4.1-27.7-1.4-7.7-3.5-15.3-4.7-23-1.4-8.6-2.1-17.3-2.9-25.9-0.9-8.6-1.3-17.3-2.4-25.9-0.6-4.7-2.3-9.4-2.4-14.1 0-2.8 0.5-5.5 1.2-8.2 0.1-0.6 0.6-1.8 0.6-1.8" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#00f200"/>   
           <!-- Синяя трасса для пешеходов -->
 <path id="blueTrace" d="m269.9 532.1c0 0 54.1-33.4 81.9-48.9 34.8-19.5 70.2-38 106.1-55.4 21.1-10.2 43-18.8 64.2-28.9 10.7-5.1 20.8-11.4 31.8-15.9 13-5.3 26.9-8 40.1-13 19.4-7.3 38.1-16.4 57.2-24.7 13.8-6 27.6-12 41.2-18.3 10.9-5 21.8-9.9 32.4-15.3 6.2-3.2 11.9-7.2 18.3-10 5.1-2.2 10.4-4.1 15.9-5.3 4.1-0.9 8.3-0.7 12.4-1.2 4.3-0.5 9.1-3.7 13-1.8 3.6 1.8 4.9 6.7 5.9 10.6 3.2 12.4-0.8 25.6 0 38.3 1 15.2 4.3 30.2 5.9 45.4 1.3 12.5 1.8 25.2 2.9 37.7 1.4 15.3 3.5 30.6 4.7 46 0.8 10.6 1.2 21.2 1.8 31.8 0.6 11.2 1.8 33.6 1.8 33.6" style="fill:none;stroke:#0000f7"/>
              <!-- Пурпурная трасса для пешеходов -->
 <path id="purpleTrace" d="m833.8 530.9c0 0-8.6-46-13-68.9-4.7-24.6-9.2-49.2-14.1-73.7-2.6-13-6.3-25.8-8.2-38.9-1.9-12.5-1.6-25.2-3.5-37.7-0.8-5.4 0.3-12-3.5-15.9-4-4.1-10.8-4.3-16.5-4.1-7.6 0.3-14.8 4.1-21.8 7.1-13.7 5.9-26 14.7-39.5 21.2-16.7 8-34.3 14.2-51.3 21.8-19.5 8.8-38.7 18-57.7 27.7-16.5 8.4-32.5 17.8-48.9 26.5-23.7 12.6-47.8 24.3-71.3 37.1-14.7 8-29.1 16.4-43.6 24.7-15 8.6-30.1 16.9-44.8 25.9-13.8 8.5-27.3 17.4-40.7 26.5-12.9 8.8-38.3 27.1-38.3 27.1" style="fill:none;stroke:#b72eba"/>   
             <!-- Чёрная трасса -->
 <path  id="blackTrace" d="m103.3 388.8c30.2-9.5 61.7-13.6 92.5-20.8 22.6-5.3 44.9-11.4 67.5-16.7 18-4.2 36.1-7.6 54.2-11.7 15.3-3.5 30.5-7.4 45.8-10.8 14.7-3.3 29.3-6.7 44.2-9.2 18.2-3 36.8-3.8 55-6.7 15.9-2.5 31.6-6.5 47.5-9.2 17.4-2.9 35-5 52.5-7.5 15-2.2 30-4.5 45-6.7 11.9-1.7 23.9-3.5 35.8-5 9.4-1.2 18.9-2.1 28.3-3.3 8.3-1 32.8-6.5 25-3.3-13.7 5.5-30.6 4.5-45.8 6.7-18.5 2.7-36.9 5.4-55.4 7.9-15.7 2.2-31.4 3.8-47.1 6.2-10 1.6-20 3.7-30 5.4-11.1 1.9-22.2 3.6-33.3 5.4-13.7 2.2-27.5 4.3-41.2 6.7-11.7 2-23.4 3.8-35 6.2-11.3 2.4-22.5 5.7-33.7 8.3-14.7 3.5-29.5 6.6-44.2 10-28.2 6.6-56.5 13-84.6 20.4-71.3 18.8-136 35-212.7 60.7-7.6 2.5-30.2 5.6-24 0.6C35.6 401.6 69.8 399.4 103.3 388.8Z" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>
      <!-- Серая трасса -->
<path id="grayTrace" d="m698.3 278-106.7 16.7-81.7 10.8-115 19.2-87.5 18.3-93.3 19.2-89.2 21.7-103.3 31.7-16.7 4.2 4.2 10 152.5-49.2 103.3-25 117.5-27.5 73.3-14.2 63.3-9.2 62.5-8.3 39.2-7.5 39.2-6.7z" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>

<path id="mostTrace1" d="M9.2 429.7 198.3 368.8 363.3 331.3l117.5-20 74.2-13.3 62.5-9.2 44.2-4.2 36.7-6.7" />
  <path id="mostTrace2" d="m685.8 276.3-75 14.2-72.5 9.2-87.5 13.3-48.3 2.5-85.8 21.7-58.3 15-78.3 18.3-76.7 18.3-70 21.7-28.3 9.2" />

                <!-- Пешеход -->
  <g id="Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,-1)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0.1s"
          dur="0.4s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
   </g>
        <!-- Градиент для сигнальных фонарей -->
   <radialGradient id="Lg" fx="50%" fy="50%"  >
   <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow"  />
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red" />
  </radialGradient>   

      <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
   <stop offset="40%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
  </linearGradient>     
    
  </defs>
                        <!-- Фон -->
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9J4U5.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/> 
            
                       <!-- Дрон -->

   <g class="drone" id="drone1" transform="scale(2.5) translate(20,20)" >
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
      <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/> 
 </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
      <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>

      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9        c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5       C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0       c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
    
      </g>   
            <!-- Анимация увеличения, уменьшения дрона -->
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="btn1.click" dur="10s" values="2.5;2;1;1.5;1.5;2.5" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />     
     <!-- Анимация движения дрона -->
    <animateMotion id="move"  begin="btn1.click+3s;move.end+1s" dur="35s" repeatCount="10" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
      <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
    </animateMotion> 
           <!-- Сигнальные фонари, камеры -->
      <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="23" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
             <animate id="op1" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op1.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </ellipse>
            <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="32" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
             <animate id="op2" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op2.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
   </ellipse>   
    </g> 
 <g id="btn1" onclick='play()' >
  <circle  cx="830" cy="50" r="12" fill="url(#gradEarth)"  /> 
  <text id="txt1" x="750" y="60" font-size="2rem" fill="crimson" >Start</text>
 </g>  
                     <!-- Блок анимации пешеходов -->
   <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an1"
       begin="btn1.click"
       dur="32s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#redTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>   
    
  <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:lime; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="btn1.click+1s"
       dur="20s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#greenTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>     
    
     <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:gold; stroke-width:2 fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an3"
       begin="btn1.click+3s"
       dur="32s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#blueTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>   
    <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:crimson; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an4"
       begin="btn1.click+3s"
       dur="40s"
       repeatCount="10"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#purpleTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>    
  <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="scale(1.2)" style="stroke:gold; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an5"
       begin="btn1.click+1s"
       dur="60s"
       repeatCount="10"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#blackTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>      
   <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="scale(1)" style="stroke:lime; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an6"
       begin="btn1.click+2s"
       dur="70s"
       repeatCount="10"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#grayTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>       
  <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="scale(1.1)" style="stroke:crimson; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an7"
       begin="btn1.click+1s"
       dur="60s"
       repeatCount="10"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#mostTrace1"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>      
   <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="scale(1.2)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an8"
       begin="btn1.click+2s"
       dur="50s"
       repeatCount="10"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#mostTrace2"/>
     </animateMotion>  
     </use>          
   
</svg>

</div>
<script>
var zodiac = new Audio();
zodiac.src = src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Mireille_Mathieu.mp3";

function play() {
  zodiac.play();
}
</script>
```

Comment: ещё бы фон бы двигался бы - некий эффект был бы реальности

Comment: @MaximLensky Благодарю. Тут идея другая была, - город неподвижный, а дрон летает и фотографирует. Планирую добавить, ещё каких нибудь эффектов, например машинки, чтобы ехали, люди шли, дирижабли, что на картинке плыли неспешно

Answer (score 6):

### Тёмная тема. Вечерний город

Рисунок выше в фотошопе сделал намного темнее, это позволило более контрастно проявить световые эффекты.

Дирижабль вырезал в фотошопе и сделал самостоятельным объектом для анимации.

К дирижаблю добавил световые эффекты, реализованные с помощью радиальных градиентов и анимации непрозрачности.

Регион действия градиента изменяется с помощью анимации атрибута `d` `path`, образующего контур

Добавлена анимация фигурок, идущих людей, их анимация достигается с помощью анимации рук и ног и движения вдоль заданного маршрута

```
<use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:yellowgreen; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="btn1.click+1s"
       dur="20s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#greenTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>    
          </use>
```

Код подробно прокомментирован

```css
.container {
width:98vw;
height:auto;
}
.drone .body  {
    fill: #111111;
    stroke:GoldenRod;
    stroke-width:0.5;
    
  }

   .wing {
    fill:gold;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: wing 5s linear forwards infinite;
  }
 

  @keyframes wing {
    100% {
        transform: rotateY(7200deg);
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class ="container">
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"  viewBox="0 0 964 538" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" border="1">
<defs>   

          <!-- Трасса полёта дрона -->
  <path id="trace" d="m67.5 74.7c0 0 250-57.3 280.8 31.7 27.3 78.8-364.7 78.1-175.7 168.6 57.2 27.4-133.6 75.2-132.7 136.3 0.4 27.7 33.7 62.3 60.8 56.7 29.1-6 19.6-56.8 35.8-81.7C172 332.1 356.5 275.2 293 245.6 165.4 186.2 429.9 139.4 429.2 66.3 428.5-0.7 476.5 31.8 495 45.5c53.2 39.5-46.1 148.9-2.5 198.9 22.2 25.6 47.4-74.7 83.4-69.9 43 5.8 47.8 115.7 74.2 106.9 58.1-19.5 7.8-198.2 76.7-192.5 64.3 5.4 72.9 133.2 40.8 189.2-17.1 30-74.9 7.2-98.3 32.5-18.9 20.4 3 65.2-20 80.8-37.8 25.7-96.9-42.2-135.8-18.3-32.1 19.7-5.1 87.4-37.5 106.7-77 45.7-276.3 45.5-265-43.3 9.5-74.9 161.9 62.4 154.8-45.1-10.1-151.8 334.5 159 445.2 100.1 39.7-21.1 76.8-74.9 65-118.3-7.7-28.4-66-17.3-75.8-45-9.9-27.9 37.3-54.4 30.8-83.3-7.3-32.8-70.2-37.3-71.7-70.8C758.1 149.2 644.6 150.1 626.3 103.4 605 48.9 580.9 163.7 525.7 127.2 398.4 42.9 69.2 91.3 69.2 91.3" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#ec0000"/>
           <!-- Красная трасса для пешеходов -->
<path id="redTrace" d="m291.7 535.6c0 0 52.2-34.2 79-50.1 24.7-14.7 50-28.4 75.4-41.8 28.4-14.9 57.3-28.8 86-43 22.7-11.3 45.4-22.8 68.4-33.6 19.3-9 38.8-17.5 58.3-25.9 14.8-6.4 29.8-12.3 44.5-18.9 13.8-6.2 27.1-13.3 41-19.4 7-3.1 13.7-7.2 21.2-8.8 6.1-1.3 18.9-0.6 18.9-0.6" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#e00"/>
             <!-- Зелёная трасса для пешеходов -->
 <path id="greenTrace" d="m826.7 535.1c0 0-3.8-25.5-5.9-38.3-2.1-12.8-4.1-25.6-6.5-38.3-2.3-12.6-5.4-25.1-7.7-37.7-1.6-9.2-2.5-18.5-4.1-27.7-1.4-7.7-3.5-15.3-4.7-23-1.4-8.6-2.1-17.3-2.9-25.9-0.9-8.6-1.3-17.3-2.4-25.9-0.6-4.7-2.3-9.4-2.4-14.1 0-2.8 0.5-5.5 1.2-8.2 0.1-0.6 0.6-1.8 0.6-1.8" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3;stroke:#00f200"/>   
           <!-- Синяя трасса для пешеходов -->
 <path id="blueTrace" d="m269.9 532.1c0 0 54.1-33.4 81.9-48.9 34.8-19.5 70.2-38 106.1-55.4 21.1-10.2 43-18.8 64.2-28.9 10.7-5.1 20.8-11.4 31.8-15.9 13-5.3 26.9-8 40.1-13 19.4-7.3 38.1-16.4 57.2-24.7 13.8-6 27.6-12 41.2-18.3 10.9-5 21.8-9.9 32.4-15.3 6.2-3.2 11.9-7.2 18.3-10 5.1-2.2 10.4-4.1 15.9-5.3 4.1-0.9 8.3-0.7 12.4-1.2 4.3-0.5 9.1-3.7 13-1.8 3.6 1.8 4.9 6.7 5.9 10.6 3.2 12.4-0.8 25.6 0 38.3 1 15.2 4.3 30.2 5.9 45.4 1.3 12.5 1.8 25.2 2.9 37.7 1.4 15.3 3.5 30.6 4.7 46 0.8 10.6 1.2 21.2 1.8 31.8 0.6 11.2 1.8 33.6 1.8 33.6" style="fill:none;stroke:#0000f7"/>
              <!-- Пурпурная трасса для пешеходов -->
 <path id="purpleTrace" d="m833.8 530.9c0 0-8.6-46-13-68.9-4.7-24.6-9.2-49.2-14.1-73.7-2.6-13-6.3-25.8-8.2-38.9-1.9-12.5-1.6-25.2-3.5-37.7-0.8-5.4 0.3-12-3.5-15.9-4-4.1-10.8-4.3-16.5-4.1-7.6 0.3-14.8 4.1-21.8 7.1-13.7 5.9-26 14.7-39.5 21.2-16.7 8-34.3 14.2-51.3 21.8-19.5 8.8-38.7 18-57.7 27.7-16.5 8.4-32.5 17.8-48.9 26.5-23.7 12.6-47.8 24.3-71.3 37.1-14.7 8-29.1 16.4-43.6 24.7-15 8.6-30.1 16.9-44.8 25.9-13.8 8.5-27.3 17.4-40.7 26.5-12.9 8.8-38.3 27.1-38.3 27.1" style="fill:none;stroke:#b72eba"/>

                <!-- Пешеход -->
  <g id="Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1,-1)">
    <path   fill="none">
         <animate
          attributeName="d"
          begin="0.1s"
          dur="0.5s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          values="M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M 0,0 0,10 0,0 M0,10 0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 l 0,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0;
                  M-3,0 0,10 3,0 M0,10 0,16 l 4,-5 M0,16 l-4,-5 M0,16 c4,4 -4,4 0,0"/>
    </path> 
      </g>



 <!-- Градиент для сигнальных фонарей -->
      <radialGradient id="Lg" fx="50%" fy="50%"  >
   <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow"  />
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red" />
  </radialGradient>    
  
          <!-- Градиент для сигнальных фонарей дирижабля -->
      <radialGradient id="Lg2" fx="50%" fy="50%"  >
   <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow"  />
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="cyan" />
  </radialGradient>    
           <!-- Градиент для конуса света дирижабля -->
      <radialGradient id="Lg3" fx="50%" fy="50%"  >
   <stop offset="20%" stop-color="yellow"   />
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="cyan" opacity="0.1"/>
  </radialGradient>   

      <linearGradient id="gradEarth">
            <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"></stop>
            <stop offset="100%" stop-color="yellowgreen" ></stop>
        </linearGradient>     
    
  </defs>  
                                <!-- Фон -->
   <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aRkK.jpg" height="100%" width="100%"/>  
    
                         <!-- Дирижабль -->
    <g id="Airship" transform="translate(400,100)">    
        
               <!-- Анимация движения дирижабля      -->
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="btn1.click" dur="120s" values="400,100;700,30;800,100;860,200;700,200;500,200;300,100;100;50;400,100;400,100" repeatCount="2" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />    
          <ellipse opacity="0.1" cx="47" cy="48" rx="5" ry="5"  fill="url(#Lg2)">
                   <animate id="op3" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op3.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
         </ellipse>   
                                    <!-- Конус света дирижабля -->
 <path id="cone"  opacity="1" fill="url(#Lg3)" transform="translate(-6,-8)" d="m53.2 50.6 6.7-1.5c0 0 0.7 2.7 0 3.7-1.4 2-4.3 2.8-6.7 2.8-2.7 0-6-0.8-7.5-3.1-0.7-1.1 0-3.9 0-3.9z" >
     <animate id="an_cone" attributeName="d"
       begin="btn1.click+4s;an_cone.end+12s" dur="4s"
       repeatCount="1" fill="freeze"
       values="
       m53.2 50.6 6.7-1.5c0 0 0.7 2.7 0 3.7-1.4 2-4.3 2.8-6.7 2.8-2.7 0-6-0.8-7.5-3.1-0.7-1.1 0-3.9 0-3.9z;
       
       m53.2 50.6 6.7-1.5c0 0 10.1 165.8 12.4 201.1 0.4 6.1-11.7 11.4-19.1 11.4-7.5 0-19.7-5.3-19.5-11.5 1.2-34 12-201.5 12-201.5z;
     m53.2 50.6 6.7-1.5c0 0 10.1 165.8 12.4 201.1 0.4 6.1-11.7 11.4-19.1 11.4-7.5 0-19.7-5.3-19.5-11.5 1.2-34 12-201.5 12-201.5z;
           
       m53.2 50.6 6.7-1.5c0 0 0.7 2.7 0 3.7-1.4 2-4.3 2.8-6.7 2.8-2.7 0-6-0.8-7.5-3.1-0.7-1.1 0-3.9 0-3.9z"
        keyTimes="0;0.25;0.75;1"
        
         
      />    
    <!-- Анимация прозрачности конуса света  -->
                      
    <!-- <animate id="airOp" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click+4s;airOp.end+8s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" /> -->
 </path>
                          <!-- Изображение дирижабля -->
        <image  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJErl.png" height="10%" width="10%"/>  
    </g> 
             <!-- Анимация увеличения, уменьшения дирижабля -->
     <animateTransform xlink:href="#Airship" attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="btn1.click" dur="35s" values="1;0.8;0.5;0.8;1.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" additive="sum" /> 
            
                       <!-- Дрон -->

   <g class="drone" id="drone1" transform="scale(2.5) translate(20,20)" >
      <g class="wing left">
        <path d="M13,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S13.6,2,13,2z"/>
            <path d="M8,2C7.4,2,0,1.6,0,1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S8.6,2,8,2z"/> 
    </g>
      <g class="wing right">
        <path d="M48,2c-0.6,0-1-0.4-1-1s0.4-1,1-1s8,0.4,8,1S48.6,2,48,2z"/>
            <path d="M43,2c-0.6,0-8-0.4-8-1s7.4-1,8-1s1,0.4,1,1S43.6,2,43,2z"/>
      </g>

      <g class="body">
        <path d="M45,0.5C45,0.2,45.2,0,45.5,0S46,0.2,46,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h0.5C48.3,6,49,6.7,49,7.5S48.3,9,47.5,9H37v0.9               c0,0.7-0.4,1.4-1,1.7l-3.6,2.1c-0.3,0.2-0.7,0.3-1,0.3h-6.9c-0.4,0-0.7-0.1-1-0.3L20,11.6c-0.6-0.4-1-1-1-1.7V9H8.5             C7.7,9,7,8.3,7,7.5S7.7,6,8.5,6H9V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5C10,0.2,10.2,0,10.5,0C10.8,0,11,0.2,11,0.5V4c0.6,0,1,0.4,1,1v1h7l0,0              c0.1-0.6,0.4-1.2,1-1.6l3.6-2.1c0.3-0.2,0.7-0.3,1-0.3h6.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,1,0.3L36,4.4C36.6,4.8,37,5.3,37,6l7,0V5c0-0.6,0.4-1,1-1V0.5z"/>
            
      </g>   
               <!-- Анимация увеличения, уменьшения дрона -->
           <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" begin="btn1.click" dur="10s" values="2.5;2;1;1.5;1.5;2.5" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />     
           <!-- Анимация движения дрона -->
          <animateMotion id="move"  begin="btn1.click+3s;move.end+1s" dur="45s" repeatCount="5" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >
            <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
          </animateMotion> 
                 <!-- Сигнальные фонари,  дрона камеры -->
            <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="23" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
                   <animate id="op1" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op1.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
         </ellipse>
            <ellipse opacity="0.2" cx="32" cy="12" rx="1.5" ry="2"  fill="url(#Lg)">
                   <animate id="op2" attributeName="opacity" begin="btn1.click;op2.end+2s" dur="1s" values="0.1;1;1;1;0" repeatCount="3" restart="whenNotActive" />
         </ellipse>         
    </g> 
    <g id="btn1" transform="translate(-730 100)" onclick='play()' >
     <circle  cx="830" cy="50" r="12" fill="url(#gradEarth)"  /> 
     <text id="txt1" x="750" y="60" font-size="2.2rem" fill="crimson" >Start</text>
 </g>  
                    <!-- Блок анимации пешеходов -->
   <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:blue; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an1"
       begin="btn1.click"
       dur="32s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#redTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>    
          </use>      
          
        <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:yellowgreen; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an2"
       begin="btn1.click+1s"
       dur="20s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#greenTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>    
          </use>        
          
            <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:gold; stroke-width:2 fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an3"
       begin="btn1.click+3s"
       dur="32s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#blueTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>    
          </use>      
            <use xlink:href="#Man" transform="translate(0,0) scale(1.2)" style="stroke:crimson; fill:black;"> 
     <animateMotion id="an4"
       begin="btn1.click+3s"
       dur="40s"
       repeatCount="20"  >
          <mpath xlink:href="#purpleTrace"/>
     </animateMotion>    
          </use>       
</svg>

</div>
<script>
var zodiac = new Audio();
zodiac.src = src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Mireille_Mathieu.mp3";

function play() {
  zodiac.play();
}

</script>
```